# Creating an ImportXML to get individual YouTube video views from the video page on any content creator, for the last 30 videos. Possible?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm wondering if it is possible to create something on Google Sheets that can take the last 30 videos from a content creator and find the total views of the last 30 uploads

Comment: yes, its possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA("https://www.youtube.com"&QUERY(QUERY(UNIQUE(
 IMPORTXML("https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC7_gcs09iThXybpVgjHZ_7g/videos","//a/@href")),
 "where Col1 contains '/watch?v='"),"limit 30"))
```

[image: 0]

```
=VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(TEXT(IMPORTXML(A2,
 "//*[contains(@class, 'watch-view-count')]"),0)," view(s)?",""))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks a Lot that's awesome. I was also wondering if there was a way to make it shorter. SO essentially to create a way to find the avg views for the last 30 videos?

Comment: sure, just wrap it in AVERAGE()

Comment: Is there a way to do it into a single cell, so essentially to find the avg of the last 10 or 30 videos within a single cell?

Comment: no, due to 2nd formula. all you can do is AVERAGE(B2:B11) and hide A and B column or move them under another sheet (Sheet2)

Comment: Thanks, need to play around with the sheets to figure out a way to only have the avg views listed next to the channel link, otherwise it'd be real messy. thanks for the help. if you figure out how to do this. lemme know thanks

Comment: Would it be possible to array the second calculation to lower traffic?

Comment: The importxml function appears to be broken. If you do TEXT(IMPORTXML("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tgbNymZ7vqY",
 "//*"),0), you get some javascript which doesn't contain the view count.