# Is it possible to use ImportXML to pull the video views from a specific youtube video's URL?

Tags: google-sheets, youtube, google-sheets-formula

I have URLs for a number of youtube videos, and I would like to use IMPORTXML to pull the video views from the video into google sheets.

There is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55028200/creating-an-importxml-to-get-individual-youtube-video-views-from-the-video-page) that shows how to pull the views from the last 30 videos from a given youtube channel. Which is similar, but i need it to be from a specific video. So it seems possible, but I can not get the formula to work.

Here is the sheet I'm using: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GfnKUWAPIqeTAMs_SdoMyg65n9hOJN28xDPGDMkwh80/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

the most reliable (and fastest) would be to use youtube api (because every time yt dudes decide to improve youtube design the `IMPORTXML` formula will case to work. over few last years this happens regularly) therefor:

make a copy of this sheet: **https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13p54p3BnhPAGopZXbUksEjja5xOcn6q-j6DqMLyzfhY/copy**

it already includes the script you just need to authorize it...

within the sheet open the script editor and click the run button

[image]

proceed and don't mind those false warnings

when done, set up an automatic Trigger like this:

[image]

then just paste youtube links into A column and all shall be populated automatically

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I will dig in further. I just requested access to the sheet :)

Comment: access granted for anyone attempting to view the sheet

Comment: I have come across two issues:

1. it won't pull the information from a video w/out 'watch' in the URL. ex: .com/c/GearKnowHow/videos?view

I used ARRAY to select everything containing watch. this is No problem.

2. The script stops if it comes across a video that it can't pull data from. Idk why these videos that is causing the issue.

here is a screenshot of the error: https://i.imgur.com/YRPEzXn.png

And here is the sheet. The video causing the issue is on row 88 of the YT tab: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yiymxgOWGAK5Va-PKDLXdyqFT7oWYNdDZLNEaS7GRmk/copy